# Const is being ignored in virtual function override

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Title kind of says it all.  I can't figure out why the compiler will allow this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
    Base() = default;
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual void set(const int a) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    Derived() = default;
        virtual ~Derived() {}
    void set(int a) override <-------const tossed out
        {
            a = 2;
            std::cout << "In derived set" << std::endl;
            my_a = a;
        }

    int my_a = 0;
};


int main()
{

        Derived d;
        d.set(4);
}
```

I understand that functionally, `const int a` and `int a` are copies - but why is the const ignored as part of the signature?

The compiler (rightfully) complains about this:

```
void test1(int a)
{
    a = 2;
}

void test2(const int a)
{
   a = 2; <------ compile error
}
```

So why does the override pass and basically allow me to do the same thing in the derived class?  Why is `const` not part of the signature for override verification?

Probably a stupid question - but I can't figure out why.

Thanks!

Comment: The `const int a` parameter, the `const` is not part of the signature.  It's a bit of a quirk of the language, and is probably explained in your introductory C++ book as a footnote somewhere.

Comment: The reason is pretty simple -- top-level `const` affects the function's own copy of the parameter, but doesn't affect the caller in any way.  You don't even need an override to see this.  Try `struct S { void f1(int); }; void S::f1(const int x) {}`

Comment: [A simpler example](https://godbolt.org/z/q8GEbPfjE)

Answer (score 3):

Top-level `const` on a function parameter in a function declaration that is not a definition has no meaning at all, just like the name of such a parameter. It is not part of the function's type or signature.

This is so because such a `const` can only possibly have a meaning for a specific definition. It has no meaning for a caller, for whom declarations are written. At the call site there is no difference in whether or not the function parameter is top-level `const`.

So

```
    virtual void set(const int a) = 0;
```

is 100% equivalent to

```
    virtual void set(int) = 0;
```

as it is also for any other function. No matter whether the function parameter is `const` in the declaration, it can always be or not be top-level `const` in a definition.

For example:

```
void f(int); // declaration, not a definition

// definition of the same function with `a` being unmodifiable in the definition
void f(const int a) { }
```

or:

```
// declaration, not a definition; `const` ignored
void g(const int); 

// definition of same function with `a` modifiable
void g(int a) { }
```

As a consequence, top-level `const` is also ignored when determining virtual function overrides.

Answer (score -2):

"In the cpp prime plus 6th edition page744, it says  "If you redefined a function in a derived class, it doesn't just override the base class declaration with the same function signature. Instead, it hides all base-class member methods of the same name, regardless of the arugment signatures." When you omit the const keyword, the Derived::set() will hide the Base::set()."
That is no good here. Forgive my shallow comprehension of this problem.

As for this statement

```
void test2(const int a)
{
    a = 2; <------ compile error
}
```

a will be a const copy of what you passed to this function, means a itself is a const, you can not modify it.

Comment: If this was true, `override` would cause a compilation error, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. As I saw the answer above, the cv-qualifier of a function's paramter is not part of the signature, so what happened here was still overidding not hiding, thank you again.